# SWIFT: invalidate()

Tags: swift, nstimer

I use NSTimer in swift

I start NSTimer on mainViewController and when I click on button I move to another view (type: Modal) and timer works in Background Everything's OK, but when I back main viewController my timer is duplicated so... How to stop timer on antoher View?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

 countDownTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerDown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Comment: where exactly in mainViewController do you start the timer? Please post the code related to the timer setup.

Comment: Apart from why, you can change `countDownTimer` to an optional and do: `countDownTimer = countDownTimer ?? NSTimer.......`

Comment: Do you want it to reset?  Or just not add a second timer?

Comment: I want cancel timer because when i back to mainView timer duplicated

Answer (score 0):

If viewDidLoad executes again when you "come back" from your modal view, you're probably not actually coming back but triggering a segue to a new instance.  If you return to the main view using an unwind segue, viewDidLoad will not execute again and you will be on your original instance if you need to stop the timer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your goal is that you don't duplicate the timer.
In order to do this you can simply check if the timer is null...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()


if(countDownTimer==nil)
{
    countDownTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerDown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

}
```